# Deserializing JSON to .net Different Object using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

First i know this question had been asked hundreds of times, but i don't know what my problem is.

I'm trying to use NewtonSoft to deserialize json string into custom object.

```
var client = new RestClient(URL);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddJsonBody(retEmployeeFilters);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        //Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetrieveEmployeeResponse>(response.Content);
```

the line

> Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

return this json

```
{"response":[{"id":3,"name":"A","email":"sansdad32a.@ds.com","mobile_number":"41","address":"B","age":20,"role":"N","hiring_date":"2053-04-03","created_at":"2016-03-16 23:49:15","updated_at":"2016-03-16 23:49:15"},{"id":4,"name":"B","email":"sansda32d32a.@ds.com","mobile_number":"41321","address":"Q","age":20,"role":"C","hiring_date":"2053-04-03","created_at":"2016-03-16 23:49:24","updated_at":"2016-03-16 23:49:24"}]}
```

and here is the RetrieveEmployeeResponse Class

```
class RetrieveEmployeeResponse 

{
    public List<Employee> response { get; set; }
    public String success { get; set; }
}
```

Employee Class

```
class Employee
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public String name {get;set;}
    public String email {get;set;}
    public String mobile_number {get;set;}
    public int age {get;set;}
    public String address {get;set;}
    public String role {get;set;}
    public String hiring_date {get;set;}
}
```

is everything that i made okay ?

with debugging the object returned here

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetrieveEmployeeResponse>(response.Content);
```

has response = null and success = null

any help ?

Comment: What `response` are you checking and where should `success` be set, since it is not part of the JSON string? Tested your code an an object is populated with the values of the JSON, except ofc for `success`

Comment: Are you sure that *Content* is not null? I did a quick test and the same code works for me..

Comment: @BerndLinde thanks for your reply, the json string already has the response (List of employees)  but it doesn't have a success string. but why the response property equal null even there are data for it in the json string to be deserialized

Comment: @bit thanks for your reply, i'm sure of course because i copied it from the output. i'm confused now :)

Comment: Are you trying to debug it on the line or after the line has been executed? If it is after, then it might have already been freed since that is the last line of the (assumed) method and all objects can be GC'd. What is the actual problem?

Comment: @BerndLinde thanks for your reply again, the actual problem is that i can't use the returned object because all it's values is null

Comment: Could you show us the  *client.Execute()* method?

Comment: @bit this is a restsharp method from the restsharp library [Link](http://restsharp.org/)

Comment: I am not understanding something. You are saying that doing `Console.WriteLine(response.Content)` returns the given JSON, but the `response` object is `null`?

Comment: i'm sorry for this misunderstanding, but the meant response for this.. class RetrieveEmployeeResponse 
{
    public List<Employee> `response` { get; set; }
    public String success { get; set; }
}

Comment: Could you state the *ContentLength* and *ContentType* properties of the response from the rest sharp client?

Comment: ContentLength = 467 . ContentType = application/json

Comment: Try `var tempStr = response.Content; var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetrieveEmployeeResponse>(tempStr);  return temp;` and see what `tempStr` and `temp` contain when debugging up to the `return temp;` line.

Comment: This one worked !! can you tell me what is the difference between this and what i was doing :D @BerndLinde thanks for your help and time

Comment: Wow, didn't really except that to work o.O Something about how `response.Content` is handled during the deserialization process seems amiss. I have this bookmarked now, will take a look later and see where the devil lives and post an answer with the explenation.

Comment: make sure to answer so i can choose your answer

Comment: Could you show what the return type was of your method? Tried to replicate the behaviour in code with a mocking service (to use RestSharp's IRestResponse object like you) and on my side the returned object was populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussions in the comments, the following code fixed the *issue*, but what the **original issue** was, is still unclear. I will update this answer if and when that becomes clear.

Changing the line `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetrieveEmployeeResponse>(response.Content);` to the below, resolved the problem of null properties in the returned object.

```
var tempStr = response.Content;
var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetrieveEmployeeResponse>(tempStr);
return temp;
```

Comment: Weird !! Worked like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You should de-serialize the json response received as

```
  string responseJson="{\"response\":[{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"A\",\"email\":\"sansdad32a.@ds.com\",\"mobile_number\":\"41\",\"address\":\"B\",\"age\":20,\"role\":\"N\",\"hiring_date\":\"2053-04-03\",\"created_at\":\"2016-03-16 23:49:15\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-03-16 23:49:15\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"B\",\"email\":\"sansda32d32a.@ds.com\",\"mobile_number\":\"41321\",\"address\":\"Q\",\"age\":20,\"role\":\"C\",\"hiring_date\":\"2053-04-03\",\"created_at\":\"2016-03-16 23:49:24\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-03-16 23:49:24\"}]}\r\n";

  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetrieveEmployeeResponse>(responseJson);
```

Your json does not have any success string that's why it is null after de-serialization.

Comment: i don't get it, with the (response) you mean which response ? i agree that the success should be null because there is no data for it in the json string but what about the response (which is list of employees)

Comment: I meant you should deserialize the json string. For employees list, you should double check the names because de-serialization will return null if names of the objects in the json strings are not matched with class properties.

Comment: they are matches since i tried to implement them manually and also via automatically generated models from json string

Comment: Try to execute the code written in my answer and please let me know the results.

Comment: It works when I try it. Can you verify again that you got the right json response?